# How to render a self-destructing paragraph at mouse position in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to get a paragraph to appear at the location of the mouse coordinates, but self-destruct after 1 second.

```
$(function(){
var fadeDelay = 1000;
var fadeDuration = 1000;
$(document).click(function(e){
    var div = $('<div class="image-wrapper">')
        .css({
            "left": e.pageX + 'px',
            "top": e.pageY + 'px'
        })
        .append($('<img src="" alt="myimage" />'))
        .appendTo(document.body);

    setTimeout(function() {
        div.addClass('fade-out');           
        setTimeout(function() { div.remove(); }, fadeDuration);
    }, fadeDelay);
});
});
```

The code above is from [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctKa4/286/) which represents the effect that I am looking for; however, it uses jQuery - while I am working with React.

I tried following this linear process:

1 - In the state, toggle a boolean with mouse clicks

```
  playerAttack = () => {
    this.setState({ hasPlayerAttacked: true })
}
```

2 - In a function, when the boolean is true, return a paragraph and set the boolean back to false

```
renderDamageDealtParagraph = () => {
  if (this.state.hasPlayerAttacked) {
    return <p>{this.state.playerAttack}</p>;
    this.setState({ hasPlayerAttacked: false });
  }
};
```

However, with this approach there were too many fallacies; main one being that upon resetting the boolean back to false, the rendered paragraph immediately disappears (instead of after a timeout of 1000ms).

What is the best wait to implement something like the linked fiddle, in ReactJS using vanilla JS?

Thanks in advance to whoever might be able to help.

Comment: Actually your approach it's ok. Basically, instead of just removing it you should add to that component the `fade-out` class.

Comment: also I don't think you need any boolean.. you can just set the classname state `className={this.state.visible}` or something

Comment: Show us the code you wrote with the problems. Not the code you are trying to match.

Comment: Have a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-raman-49px5 (it accounts for multiple clicks, as the original does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically do something like this:

1. Have state to track the mouse position `x` and `y`, and two booleans `isShown` and `shouldHide` to coordinate the disappering div
2. On click, show the div by setting `isShown` to `true` and immediately `setTimeout` to start hiding it in the future by adding a class by flipping the `shouldHide` to `true`
3. Once the class is added, the element will fade and will trigger the `transitionend` event at which point you can remove the div entirely by flipping the `isShown` to `false` and `shouldHide` to false boolean

Sample Implementation (Sorry for the shitty code, been a while since I React-ed)

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6qxr5g8/18/)

---

```
class SelfDestructDemo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      isShown: false,
      shouldHide: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
  }
  reset() {
    this.setState({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      isShown: false,
      shouldHide: false
    });
  }
  handleClick(event) {
    if (this.state.isShown) {
      return;
    }
    const { clientX, clientY } = event;
    this.setState({
      x: clientX,
      y: clientY,
      isShown: true,
      shouldHide: false
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ shouldHide: true });
    }, 1000);
  }
  render() {
    const p = this.state.isShown && (
      <div
        onTransitionEnd={this.reset}
        className={`${this.state.shouldHide ? "should-hide" : ""} modal`}
        style={{ top: this.state.y, left: this.state.x }}
      >
        Self destructing....
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div className="container" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {p}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SelfDestructDemo />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```